# Upgraded to phonegap 1.1 on Android - now half the screen is half black, half white

Tags: android, cordova, view

I've written a simple hello world in PhoneGap 0.9.5.1 for Android which works fine. Recently, I upgraded to 1.1. and I get a half white half black screen (divided horizontally).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by removing

```
super.init();
```

from the droidgap activity's onCreate method.

Odd, I read somewhere you needed this for 1.1 to work.